# What is the purpose of /Users/Shared/adi?

Tags: time-machine, high-sierra

While backing up my macOS using *Time Machine* I came across the following folder: **`/Users/Shared/adi`**.

What is the purpose of that folder? Can this entry be safely removed?

[image: macOS High Sierra, Time Machine, /Users/Shared/adi]

Btw. There is already some [blog post](http://galvanist.com/post/66313155502/userssharedadi) about it, but it really doesn't clear it up.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Apparently, these files somehow belong to the Mac App Store and the iBooks app. "adi" might be referencing "Apple Distribution International". Removal from the excluded Time Machine items is not recommended, as this behaviour does seem to be expected from all macOS installs >= 10.8 Mountain Lion.

Full explanation here: http://galvanist.com/post/66313155502/userssharedadi

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth research @senthor I was also wondering why this empty `adi` folder was in `Shared`.

Comment: The link to the post is dead, but here's another link that works to the same post: https://galvanist.com/posts/2013-11-07-userssharedadi/